# Using PHPMailer with yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to send email via site/contact using PHPMailer. In my actionContact I have code:

```
require '/../../common/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
...
```

I put everything in common/phpmailer directory. In "common" directory in root folder of advanced template. I'm getting error

```
Class 'backend\controllers\PHPMailer' not found
```

This way worked fine in yii1, but not in yii2

Comment: Can't because PHPMailer class is not part of SiteController. PHPMailer is in file class.phpmailer.php in common/phpmailer folder of advanced yii2 template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do a

```
use [NAMESPACE]/PHPMailer;
```

at the top of your file.

Also Yii comes already with swiftmailer, if you do not want to use it you can always just install a new mailer

this ones come with phpmailer already in the package. It also comes with a cronjob because you do not really want to send emails directly, it takes too long usually.
https://packagist.org/packages/rmrevin/yii2-postman

this ones integrates better with yii as a component
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/zyx-phpmailer/

I personally use Mailchimp as it makes sending emails easy and I do not care to debug a mailserver when things do not go ok or when you are put on spam lists.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate what [NAMESPACE] should be using?Thanks